# Problems with virtualenvwrapper teriminal startup

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, pip

Recently I installed virtualenvwrapper using pip, and now every time that I start the terminal (I use Ubuntu16.04)it shows me this:

```
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/premkproject
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/postmkproject
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/initialize
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/premkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/postmkvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/prermvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/postrmvirtualenv
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/jorge/.virtualenvs/get_env_details
```

How can I can stop these messages?

Comment: So even when you launch a normal terminal you get this message?

Comment: How did it modify your startup files?